# TypeError: undefined is not an object- git push fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git

I have an angular code which runs fine on the machine with no error, then i want to commit the changes to git, my commit cmd ran successfullly but push fails saying:

**PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Controller: BasicInfo... controller navigation... save and go to summary FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.responseMessage')**

**data.responseMessage holds bool value**. I thought of adding a condition check for undefined as below but no luck.

```
 if(data.responseMessage !== 'Undefined' {
    res = data.responseMessage;
 }
```

My actual partial code is here:

```
       function save() {
          if(vm.basicInfoForm.$valid) {
            blockUI.start('Saving personal information');
            employeeService.setEmployee(vm.employee)
                .then(function Success(data) {
                    res = data.responseMessage;
```

The value for data.response is coming from employee.js file and below is the code:

```
   function setEmployee(employee) {
        _employee = null;
        return Restangular.one('someURL').customPUT(employee)
            .then(function Success(data) {
                var responseData = {
                    responseMessage: data.isAddressChanged,
                    employeeData : _employee
                };
                return responseData;
            })
            ['catch'](function Failure() {
                var responseData = {
                    responseMessage: false,
                    employeeData : null
                };
                return responseData;
            });
    }
```

I think it could be because of some test case failure while git push.
Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
Haseena

Comment: If `data.responseMessage` is a boolean then `data.responseMessage !== 'Undefined'` will always return *true* since you are strictly comparing a string to a boolean (and different Types are never strictly equivalent). But your error stems from *data* being undefined (apparently).

Comment: i tried the condition check but removed it later on

Comment: updated by question for the source of data.response

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by storing only data object in res as

```
    res=data;
```

and later in the code i used

```
    if(res.responsemessage.isAddressChange) {}
```